# How to define the subfigure format with \renewcommand

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I am trying to define the figure and subfigure formats when creating cross-references in latex. I have this command:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{S(\alph{subfigure})}
```

When I cross-reference the figure, I have for example: `Fig. S1.`
But if I cross-reference the subfigure, I have `Fig. 1S(c)`.

However what I want to have this format like `Fig. S1(c)`. How can I get the this output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you use the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Instead of  adding S in `\thesubfigure` one can use `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=...}` to add the S.  One can also use `\captionsetup{subrefformat=...}`to format `\subref` (or `\ref{sub@...}`) independently.  See pages 11 & 12 of the subcaption manual.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of two lines of code only? This would help us to help you, because we would not need to guess, which packages you are using for the subfigures and how you are referencing etc.

Comment: You can change the format of subfigure cross-references by redefining \p@subfigure, which is the prefix used when cross-referencing subfigures. Here’s an example that should give you the desired output:  \makeatletter \renewcommand{\thefigure} S\arabic{figure}} \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})} \renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure} \makeatother´´´
This will change your subfigure cross-reference format to Fig. S1(c). Is this what you were looking for?